# Proof that if an algebraic integer is rational, it is integer?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, reference-request

There is a well-known fact that the intersection of  and ℚ is ℤ. It is mentioned in many places, including [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_integer), without proof. Does this theorem have a well-known name, and where can i find the proof?

Comment: Wikipedia lists it as the Integral Root Theorem; a special case of the [Rational Root Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem).

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones It appears to be an invented name, since i can’t find any outside sources, but thanks. This is sufficient for me

Comment: This is essentially a consequence of Gauss's Lemma http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_(polynomial)

Comment: Beware that  denotes the algebraic _numbers_ (roots of polynomials with integral coefficients) rather than the algebraic _integers_ (which is the subset where the polynomial is also *monic*, i.e had leading coefficient 1). The latter set might be denoted as something like "*", but I'm not sure of what conventions exist.

Comment: @Rhubbarb I only knew the convention that  is algebraic integers and ℚ̅ is the algebraic numbers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In elementary contexts, one can refer to this as the *monic* case of the  [Rational Root test (RRT)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem).

More generally, $\,\Bbb Z\,$ is [integrally closed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrally_closed_domain) (in $\Bbb  Q),\,$ since $ $ Euclidean $\,\Rightarrow$ PID $\Rightarrow$ gcd domains are integrally-closed (the  proof of RRT in $\,\Bbb Z\,$ immediately generalizes to any domain with gcds).